# Google Colab 上の pip で openjij をインストールしようとするとエラーが発生する

Tags: google-colaboratory, pip

Google Colaboratoryでopenjijをimportしようとしましたがうまくいきません。
実行したコマンドは次のものです。

```
pip install openjij
```

これを実行すると以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
   Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting openjij
  Downloading openjij-0.5.1.tar.gz (2.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.3 MB 5.3 MB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting typing-extensions<4.3.0,>=4.2.0
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting jij-cimod<1.5.0,>=1.4.1
  Downloading jij_cimod-1.4.3.tar.gz (83 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 83 kB 76 kB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting scipy<1.9.0,>=1.7.3
  Downloading scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (38.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 38.1 MB 1.2 MB/s 
Collecting dimod<=0.10.17
  Downloading dimod-0.10.17-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (13.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 13.2 MB 34.6 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.23.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from openjij) (1.21.6)
Collecting requests<2.29.0,>=2.28.0
  Downloading requests-2.28.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 62 kB 614 kB/s 
Collecting pyparsing<3.0.0,>=2.4.7
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 67 kB 6.9 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<2.29.0,>=2.28.0->openjij) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<2.29.0,>=2.28.0->openjij) (2022.6.15)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<2.29.0,>=2.28.0->openjij) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<2.29.0,>=2.28.0->openjij) (1.24.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: openjij, jij-cimod
  Building wheel for openjij (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for openjij
  Building wheel for jij-cimod (PEP 517) ... canceled
```

参考にしたサイトは以下のものです。

[OpenJij 入門](https://colab.research.google.com/github/OpenJij/OpenJijTutorial/blob/master/source/ja/001-Introduction.ipynb#scrollTo=JZW9IAE9QyOd)

回答のほどどうかお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

原因はわかりませんが、[openjij本家のURL](https://tutorial.openjij.org/build/html/ja/005-OpenJijGPU.html#Google-Colab%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%A8%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)を見ると「Google Colabでの設定とインストール」のところに以下の順で行うように書いてあります。

```
!pip install -U cmake
!pip uninstall openjij -y
!pip install openjij --no-binary :all: --no-cache-dir
```

こちらに従って試してみてはいかがでしょうか？

なお私のGoogle Colab環境(2022/07/11現在。7/1に最新版がリリースされているようです)では`pip install openjij`のみでインストールすることができました。